# Getting data from sqlite database and putting into expandable list?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have some data stored in sqlite database in different tables. For example I get Tutorial titles from table name main_category and tutorial description from table tutorials and i want to show them in expandable listview. But i am getting nullpointer exception.
This is my code to get values from sqlite database.

```
 public List<String> getTutNames() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select cat_name From main_category;", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}

public List<String> getTutDes() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select tut_detail From tutorials;", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

And this is my code to put it in expandable listview.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView elv;
List<String> listDataHeader;
List<String> listChild;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elv);

    DatabaseAccess db = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    db.open();
    listDataHeader = db.getTutNames();
    listChild = db.getTutDes();
    db.close();

    for (int i=0; i<listDataHeader.size();i++) {
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), listChild);
    }

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    elv.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this! may help

And check the logcat while retriving data.

```
public List<String> getTutNames() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select cat_name From main_category;", null);
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return list;
}

public List<String> getTutDes() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select tut_detail From tutorials;", null);
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Mohammad nabil, I tried but still no success. NullpointerException at this line. for (int i=0; i<listDataChild.size();i++) {

Comment: @SilentCoder then where you initializing listDataChild, i can not see initialization in your code.

Comment: @Pavan, sorry i was suppose to write listDataHeader.size(). Now i edited my code. Still NullpointerException but now on line 41.             listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), listChild);

Comment: @SilentCoder obviously u will get that because listDataChild is null before using  initialize it

Comment: @Pavan, thanx bro. I got it working after initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your query database need some time. You can add synchronized to method and check list null when use.

Comment: Thanx bro. Can u answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095633/data-is-coming-from-sqlite-database-and-arrange-it-in-expandable-listview

Comment: Ok. Wait me coding.

Comment: My project maybe can help you! https://github.com/HoangDang/SugarORMDatabase/tree/master/SugarORMDatabase